# On QGIS2.4 how can i represent a sens of circulation?

Tags: qgis-2.4

I'm working on the creation of a map of the third arrondissement of Lyon (France).
I'm using free informations from the web site "SmartData" of ("Le Grand Lyon).
I'm trying to represent roads, under QGIS 2.4, with arrows for the representation of the circulation (Oneway).
In my colonn i have 'FT' if it's in the sens of the circulation and 'TF' if it's on the other sens. So i want that the arrow go on inverse sens.
How can i do this with Qgis ?!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE! As the Symbol layer type, are you using **Simple lines** or **Marker lines**?

Comment: I'm using Marker lines.

Comment: The marker line for your arrows, if you select the **Data defined properties** menu > select **Angle** and set the column of the Expression to something like `CASE WHEN "TF" IS "TF" THEN '180.0' END`. You may need to include the attribute value for the "TF" column into the expression.

Comment: Thanks for these informations. I have changed the image. i think it's more explicit now. I just want to change the sens of the road when the information is 'TF' ... it's not so simple indeed ....